# How to use methods of Mocked component - Jasmine (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, overriding, karma-jasmine

I am using [this](https://github.com/cnunciato/ng2-mock-component) library to Mock components in my unit test cases.

Now whenever I test a method which uses a method of subComponent then it throws error that:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodOfChildComponent' of undefined
```

I saw in this [link](https://medium.com/@cnunciato/a-simple-mock-component-for-angular-2-d79bd58a7b31) that using `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` or `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` will make my `test cases` to exclude `child components`.

But In my case this also doesn't work. I tried with both but I am always getting same error.

Is their any method out there by which I can use `childComponent's` method inside my test case. SO that I won't get any error while running `ng test`.

**EDIT**

I have already added :

```
MockComponent({
      selector: 'sel-p,
      inputs: ['name'],
    }),
```

and imported  `import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';`

and added `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],` I also tried with `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` but none of them seems working.

**Note**
By searching I found that I can use [overrideComponent](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/components/overriding.html) to override child component. But I am not able find any example for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; to your spec file, and inside your TestBed.configureTestingModule add the schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

You'll need to create a mock child directive that has the same selector as your child component and bring that in to your declarations array so that it can use it. The mock child directive just needs to have as much stuff from the original component that you need in order to run the test.